# Biggest lobby firms for labor

Tags: united-states, employment

I am trying to find out which lobbyists do the most work for organized labor in the United States. I have done a Google search but have not come up with anything meaningful.

Comment: I'm not sure what you consider meaningful but a quick search returned the [lobbyists of AFL-CIO](https://www.opensecrets.org/lobby/clientlbs.php?id=D000000088&year=2017). The same site seems to have donors, spending, among other stats. According to its wikipedia page this organization seems credible.

Comment: @armatita  Which organization?  The [AFL-CIO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AFL%E2%80%93CIO) is a federation of unions, but not all unions belong to them.  Beyond that, unions that do belong may also use separate lobbyists for their own purposes.  Note that that list is mostly lobbyists employed directly by the AFL-CIO, not firms that lobby generally but mostly for labor.

Comment: By organization I meant the very Open Secrets you've mentioned in your answer. Erratum: "According to its wikipedia page this **research group** seems credible." (btw I noticed the down vote, it's not mine)

Answer (score 1):

Open Secrets' [Labor sector](https://www.opensecrets.org/lobby/indus.php?id=P&year=2017) list might be what you want.  Depends on how much one trusts [Open Secrets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSecrets.org)' categorizations.

A starting point at least.